# Disable android charging without using root

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am developing Mobile test automation tool and I have encountered a problem regarding disabling the charging capability of Android device without using root.

I have been searching the net about using Raspberry PI to solve my problem. Unfortunately, the solution I found is not possible since using the `shutdown` command will disable the capability of the USB of raspberry PI to received other android commands other than the charging command.

Does anybody have any suggestion on how I can achieve my goal?

The end goal is this: The charging of the android phone will be disable while the USB is connected in the Computer/Raspberry PI, but I must be able to send other adb commands (like call command, messaging command, command that can swipe phone) to the attached phone.

Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

use the rasberry Pi to only send power to the data lines on your cable and not +- so that it only sends power to data line and this should work. and you can do this with some editing of the port config but this will also make anything you plug into the port a dud.

Comment: Thanks 
Union Memeory Server . I am quite new with raspberry PI, what do you mean by the "+-"? Also if you can provide some diagrams or the likes, it will be very helpful for me. Thank you very much